# Need assistance with PowerShell Script to clean up computers in AD that meet criteria

Tags: powershell, scripting, active-directory

Hello & thanks in advance for the help!
Looking to delete computers (Workstations OU) in AD if they meet a certain criteria.

I need to make sure they have the "LOCATION," part of the Canonical name in common before proceeding to delete. If they are not at my location that could be reason to investigate and I do not want to delete them. This is an example of one PC (Caps are fields I changed):

```
ORGANIZATION.COM/Workstations/BUSINESS UNIT/Desktops/LOCATION/COMPUTER NAME
```

I have the following script currently that will print them to a .csv which is helpful, but to take it one step further, it would be nice to print this on the screen then review it quick and proceed with a delete. Any tips??

```bsh
Get-Content C:\Temp\Powershell\hosts.txt | ForEach-Object {
  Get-ADComputer $_ -Properties Name,CanonicalName |Select-Object Name,CanonicalName
} -ErrorAction Ignore | Export-Csv C:\Temp\Powershell\Output.csv
```

Or even a second line of code I can utilize the output.csv with, not sure where to go from here...

Again, Thanks!

Comment: This script kind of does what I'm trying to achieve... Get-Content ComputersToDelete.txt | % { Get-ADComputer -Filter { Name -eq $_ } } | Remove-ADComputer -WhatIf                                        
    ........................................................                                  
I can review with the -WhatIf command, then proceed without it after reviewing

Comment: Getting this error running the above command without "WhatIf" :......................................................................................................................

Remove-ADComputer : The directory service can perform the requested operation only on a leaf object
At line:1 char:91
+ ... xt | % { Get-ADComputer -Filter { Name -eq $_ } } | Remove-ADComputer

Answer (score 0):

Added -Recursive and it seems to be working as expected.

Comment: None of the commands in your original question have a `-Recursive` parameter, so what exactly did you add it to? Might be useful for future readers if you post the full script/solution in your answer :)